# How do i combine the Multiple Assertion with MSTEST (Specflow)

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, specflow

Below is the assertions for my Test
How i can combine all the assertions in one line of code

```
public void ThenICanSeeTheFunctionlitiesForNONtransitionUserAsClnician()
{
  Assert.IsTrue(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList().Contains("Show menu"));
  Assert.IsTrue(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList().Contains("Patient Summary"));
  Assert.IsTrue(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList().Contains("Patient Encounter"));
 }
```

Comment: You might want to explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumptions**

- `ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList()` returns `IEnumerable<string>`
- You can use MSTest assertions

First we need to create a collection of items which we expect to have in the "MenuList" and what we actually have

```cs
var expectedItems = new List<string> { "Show menu", "Patient Summary", "Patient Encounter" };
var actualItems = ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList();
```

Now you have two options based on what you need:

**1. You want to check if the "MenuList" contains those 3 items (but not strictly only those)**

```
CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(expectedItems, actualItems);
```

**2. You want to check if the "MenuList" contains *only* those 3 items (nothing else)**

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedItems, actualItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Specflow multiple assertion if u want your assertions keep running if one of them are failed:

```
    public void ThenICanSeeTheFunctionlitiesForNONtransitionUserAsClnician()
        {
        Assert.Multiple(() =>
            {
          Assert.IsTrue(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList().Contains("Show menu"));
          Assert.IsTrue(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList().Contains("Patient Summary"));
        Assert.IsTrue(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList().Contains("Patient Encounter"));
            });
    }
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't know u should try and me know, but I'm using it with NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally just want one Assert, Technically, you could do something like this:

```
public void ThenICanSeeTheFunctionlitiesForNONtransitionUserAsClnician()
{
    var menuItems = ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList();
    Assert.IsTrue(menuItems.Contains("Show menu") && menuItems.Contains("Patient Summary") && menuItems.Contains("Patient Encounter"));
}
```

But then I believe you'd lose visibility into exactly what menu item was missing when the test fails. The way you already have it now makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and as you said the one i wrote has more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want readability in your test method you could introduce a private method that has all your assertions in e.g.

```
public void ThenICanSeeTheFunctionlitiesForNONtransitionUserAsClnician() 
{
  AssertMenuListItems(ObjectRepository.phPage.GetMenuList());
}

private void AssertMenuListItems(TypeOfGetMenuList items) 
{
  Assert.IsTrue(items.Contains("Show menu"));
  Assert.IsTrue(items.Contains("Patient Summary"));
  Assert.IsTrue(items.Contains("Patient Encounter"));
}
```